# Quadratic Integer Ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-14}]$, show that $7+\sqrt{-14} \notin (7)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quadratic-integer-rings

I just want to make sure I am getting this correct, as I am just learning ring theory and quadratic integer rings.

Let $\alpha = 7 + \sqrt{-14}$.

To show that $\alpha \notin (7)$ I will show a contradiction. If we assume that $\alpha \in (7)$, then there must exist some element $q \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-14}]$ such that $7q=\alpha$. Let $q = c + d\sqrt{-14}$, then this amounts to finding $c$ and $d$ $\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that 
$$(7+0\sqrt{-14})(c+d\sqrt{-14})=(7+\sqrt{-14})$$
. Since $7c +0d\sqrt{-14}=7$, this implies that $c = 1$. We also must have that $7d\sqrt{-14} + 0c\sqrt{-14} = 1\sqrt{-14} \implies 7d=1$ which is impossible for $d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So we must not assume that $\alpha \in (7)$, so $\alpha \notin (7)$.

Comment: If you are aware of norms, you can simply say: if $7+\sqrt{-14}\in (7)$, we must have $N(7)|N(7+\sqrt{-14})$, i.e. $49|63$, which is impossible.

Comment: Your proof is simple, direct and correct.

Comment: @Caffeine I am learning about norms now but still not familiar with this property you show. Would you have a reference with more about that property?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind the norm is multiplicative, i.e. $N(ab)=N(a)N(b)$. In general, $a\in (b)$ iff $\exists c: bc=a$, which implies $N(b)N(c)=N(a)$, and thus $N(b)|N(a)$. This method is quite standard in examining whether an element is contained in a principal ideal.

Comment: **Or** $\ 7\mid 7\!+\!\sqrt{-14}\iff 7\mid\sqrt{-14}\,\overset{\rm square}\Longrightarrow 7^{\large 2}\mid 14\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow\ \ $

Comment: The proof seems to *implicitly* use: if $\,j,k\in\Bbb Z\,$ then $\,j+k\sqrt{-14} = j'+k'\sqrt{-14}\,\Rightarrow\, j=j',k=k'.\,$ This may need *explicit* justification (depending on the context).